# Fragment in FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-layout, fragmentpageradapter

I want a tab with 4 scrollable tabs in a class. I implemented the following example and it works:

```
mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
mViewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

...

```
public static class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_ITEMS;  //NUM_ITEMS=4
    }
    @Override
    public ArrayListFragment getItem(int position) {
        return ArrayListFragment.newInstance(position);
    }
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch(position) {
        case 0:
            return "TAB1";
        case 1:
            return "TAB2";
        case 2:
            return "TAB3";
        case 3:
            return "TAB4";
        default:
            return "ERROR";
        }       
    }
}
```

...

```
    public static class ArrayListFragment extends ListFragment {
    int mNum;

    static ArrayListFragment newInstance(int num) {
        ArrayListFragment f = new ArrayListFragment();

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("num", num);
        f.setArguments(args);

        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mNum = getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getInt("num") : 1;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        switch(mNum) {
        case 0:
            View v0 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pager_list, container, false);
            return v0;
        case 1:
            View v1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pager_list, container, false);
            return v1;
        case 2:
            View v2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pager_list, container, false);
            return v2;
        case 3:
            View v3 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pager_list, container, false);
            return v3;
        default:
            View vd = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pager_list, container, false);
            return vd;              
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Titles)); 
    }
    //Titles={"TAB1", "TAB2", "TAB3", "TAB4"}
    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        Log.i("FragmentList", "Item clicked: " + id);
    }


}
```

where fragment_pager_list layout that I put in each view is the following:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:drawable/gallery_thumb">

<TextView android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="HELLO WORLD"/>

<!-- The frame layout is here since we will be showing either
the empty view or the list view.  -->
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
    <!-- Here is the list. Since we are using a ListActivity, we
         have to call it "@android:id/list" so ListActivity will
         find it -->
    <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"/>

    <!-- Here is the view to show if the list is emtpy -->
    <TextView android:id="@android:id/empty"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="No items."/>

</FrameLayout>
```

The problem is that I want to put a different layout in each view for each tab.
I tried to modify the code so that "ArrayListFragment" inherits from "Fragment" instead of "ListFragment" to load layouts that do not contain "ListView" but "RelativeLayout" or "LinearLayout", but can not get it to work.

Please, if anyone can help me, I need to load different views on the tabs and that they contain other elements than ListView.

Thank you very much.

Comment: By using ListFragment automatically detects ListView in layout ... what I have to implement in the layout to the method detect it using Fragment instead of ListFragment , and can see it in the view for each tab? A <fragment ... > </fragment> ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd better make each fragment for different layout.
You can add `addFragment(Fragment fragment)` method to `MyAdapter`.

```
mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
for(int i=0; i<4; i++) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch(i) {
    case 0: 
        fragment = FirstFragment.newInstance();
        break;
    case 1:
        fragment = SecondFragment.newInstance();
        break;
    case 2:
        fragment = ThirdFragment.newInstance();
        break;
    case 3:
        fragment = FourthFragment.newInstance();
        break;
    }
    mAdapter.addFragment(fragment);
}
mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
mViewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

MyAdapter : Adapter is a simple container.

```
public static class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private List<Fragment> mFragmentList;

    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        mFragmentList = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
    }

    publid void addFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return ((CustomFragment) mFragmentList.get(position)).getPageTitle();
    }
}
```

CustomFragment : Put common methods for each fragments.

```
public abstract class CustomFragment extends Fragment {
    public abstract Fragment newInstance();
    public abstract String getPageTitle();
}
```

FirstFragment : Inflate different layout for each fragments.

```
public class FirstFragment extends CustomFragment {

    @Override
    public Fragment newInstance() {
        Fragment f = new FirstFragment();
        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.LAYOUT_ID_FOR_FIRST_FRAGMENT, container, false);

        // Some codes for layout such as findViewById

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPageTitle() {
        // return TITLE_FOR_FRAGMENT
    }
}
```

I hope this answer will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the help Raegon. I'm testing the code but lack the method "newInstance" in every method of Fragment (FirstFragment, ...), which you call in the first switch.

Comment: Moreover, FirstFragment should be static method to call it in switch not?

Comment: I Added abstract `newInstance` method to `CustomFragment`.

Comment: I made the latest changes, but I have some errors in each Fragment extends CustomFragment: "No enclosing instance of type IniSelCategory (the class name) is available due to some intermediate constructor invocation" ... and I have put static the "newInstance" method, then I have next mistake: "This static method cannot hide the instance method from IniSelCategoria.CustomFragment"...help me please! Thank you.

Comment: It is solved, I had to put static methods and remove anything else. 
But now how I interact with elements from each Fragment of each tab? 
I tested this on onCreateView method:
            ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img1);
            img.setOnClickListener(new ImageView.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(View v) {
               Log.i("Fragment", "This is a test"); 
           }
            });
I have next mistake in "findViewById":
"Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method findViewById(int) from the type SherlockFragmentActivity"